# synchronize clocks on multiple 1804 linux mini computers without internet

Tags: networking, sync, time

I have a mobile platform that contains more than 1 ubuntu 1804 linux computer on it. All of these computers are connected to a router hosting a local ethernet network. All of the computers need to set their local, internal clocks to the same time. Neither the router nor any of the computers have access to the internet. They can communicate to each other through the router. Other than not having internet access, there aren't any constraints to the local network communication.

How do I get all of these computers to synchronize their clocks?

I should also mention that it is not unusual for either or all of the devices to power cycle (reboot) during operation, so the clocks need to be check and then re-synchronized all the time.

I have done some research on the internet about `ntp`, `timedatectl`, and `chrony`, but everything I see assumes internet access. I have also heard that `ntp` is outdated and there are more modern programs that work better, but I don't have the know how to prove or disprove this claim.

For more background knowledge, I am referencing the [Jetson](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/autonomous-machines/embedded-systems/) platform.

I am hoping to add other computers as well, like a [Raspberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/) computer.

Comment: NTP does not assumes there is an Internet connection (non non non) - You can setup a local ntp server and make ntp clients pointing to it - Some docs are avaiable, search for `stratum` - A faster protocol is called PTP, the two dominant protocols are NTP and GPS !!!

Comment: So what commands do I have to run? I do not know commands to run given your comment. I googled `stratum` but I do not know what I am looking for. I am confused by your comment.

Comment: http://www.ntp.org/ntpfaq/NTP-s-algo.htm